# fallo al enviar datos con sessions en php en la misma pagina

Tags: php, array, formularios

Hola soy novata en PHP estoy realizando un ejercicio tengo que hacerlo en una única pagina. Lo que intento es que cuando añadimos una tarea se muestre el listado y se vayan añadiendo a la lista, consegui guardar los datos con un session pero me los guarda no como quiero. Si introduzco como tareas 1 me aparece el 1 pero si introduzco 2 desparece y si intruduzco 3 me aparece la lista pero e 1 y 3 y asi sucesivamente.
Al inspeccionar el elemento en navegador me doy cuenta que el problema que mi session solo captura lo que haya en pantalla cuando se le pasa. He intentado varios if y varias colocaciones pero no doy con mi error. Dejo aquí el código, tengo que decir que el código esta incompleto y se puede mejorar pero estoy haciendo el ejercicio poco a poco para los problemas de 1 en 1 y lo iré mejorando.
** actualizacion como ha dicho el compañero pongo el session start arriba con su configuracion pero eso no me cambia la salida:

```
 <?php
            session_start(); //inicio sesion para guardar los datos
            if(!isset($_SESSION['datos'])){ // si no hay datos creeamos el array
                $_SESSION['datos'] = array(); 
                    }
            if(!empty($_POST['listado'])){
                $listado=explode(",",$_POST['listado']);
            }else{
                $listado = array();
            }
            
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Agenda de Tareas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <h1>Agenda de Tareas</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Nueva Tarea:</legend>
                    <label for="tarea">Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tarea"/> !<!-- creo un input oculto para el array. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="listado" value="<?php echo implode(",", $_SESSION['datos'])?>"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" name="añadir">Añadir Tarea</button>
                    <button type="reset">Limpiar Campos</button>
                    
                </fieldset>           
        
            <br>
            <?php 
                if(!empty($_POST['tarea'])){
                  
                    $nuevatarea=$_POST['tarea']; 
                    
                    
                    array_push($listado, $nuevatarea);
                    $_SESSION['datos']=$listado;
                    
                    ?>  
             <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                    <?php 
                       for($i=0; $i < count($listado); $i++){
                           echo $listado[$i]."<br/>";
                       }
                
                }
                
                    ?>
                </fieldset>  
            </div>
        </form>
          
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="tarea">Num Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="selecTarea"/>
                    <button type="button"id="completarTarea"> Tarea Completada</button>
                    <input type="button" id="borrarTarea" value="Tarea Borrada"/>
                    <br><!-- comment -->
                    <input type="button" id="vaciar" value="Vaciar Agenda"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu código php no debería estar encima de tu estructura html?...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev  me piden el codigo todo en la misma página mezclado si que es verdad que como dice el compañero el session tiene que ir arriba. y me faltaria la validación de datos y todo eso que tambien iria arriba. Pero voy con los problemas de uno en uno. Y el problema que me surge el la salida de la información que mel hace alternativamente

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
```

No puede estar después de escapar algo al navegador.

Las secciones son funciones o métodos que se ejecutan en el server antes de enviar datos al navegador, por lo que no tiene que haber nada escapado al navegador antes de ejecutar esa función, pues en función de lo que se solicite se cambiaran las cabeceras de respuesta a la petición http.

Lo que se escapa esta en el cuerpo del mensaje y las sesiones en la cabecera, por ende php no puede modificar la cabecera después de enviada.

En resumen esto debería funcionar

```php
<?php
session_start(); //inicio sesion para guardar los datos
if(!isset($_SESSION['datos'])){ // si no hay datos creeamos el array
    $_SESSION['datos'] = array(); 
        }
if(!empty($_POST['listado'])){
    $listado=explode(",",$_POST['listado']);
}else{
    $listado = array();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

añado mas para responder a tus dudas.

las sesiones estan en el servidor y estas no se deben reenviar pues queda almacenado hasta que tu le indiques lo contrario o se borre la session.

```php
<?php

    session_start(); //inicio sesion para guardar los datos
    if(!isset($_SESSION['datos'])){ // si no hay datos creeamos el array
        $_SESSION['datos'] = array(); 
    }else{
      $listado=$_SESSION['datos']; // si ya hay datos los agrega a listado
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['tarea'])){ si se envia una tarea se suma al listado y se sobre escribe la variable de sesion
      $nuevatarea=$_POST['tarea']; 
      array_push($listado, $nuevatarea);
      $_SESSION['datos']=$listado;
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Agenda de Tareas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <h1>Agenda de Tareas</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Nueva Tarea:</legend>
                    <label for="tarea">Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tarea"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" name="añadir">Añadir Tarea</button>
                    <button type="reset">Limpiar Campos</button>
                    
                </fieldset>           
        
            <br>
             <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
             <?php 
                if(count($listado)>0){ //cambia por si hay datos en el listado
                
                   for($i=0; $i < count($listado); $i++){
                       echo $listado[$i]."<br/>";
                   }
                
                }
                
             ?>
                </fieldset>  
            </div>
        </form>
          
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="tarea">Num Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="selecTarea"/>
                    <button type="button"id="completarTarea"> Tarea Completada</button>
                    <input type="button" id="borrarTarea" value="Tarea Borrada"/>
                    <br><!-- comment -->
                    <input type="button" id="vaciar" value="Vaciar Agenda"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tiene sentido, soy nueva y no habia entendido esa parte del session pero al ponerlo arriba no me cambia el asunto sigue generando la misma respues solo me almacena lo que tiene en la pantalla si se envia por lo tanto me guarda en alternos @John

Comment: allí modifique la respuesta, para echarte una mano